# Как правильно забрать данные с сервера используя Vue, Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Учусь писать на vuejs. Есть компонент c кнопкой, при клике хочу получить данные и записать их в store. Как правильно это реализовать? Нашел 2 решения, какое из них правильное  или может оба не правильные? И почему?

В первом вариант делаю запрос используя actions, во втором прямо из компонента.

Вариант 1

```js
<!-- STORE -->
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    items: []
  },
  getters: {
    getItems(state) {
      return state.items
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    updateItems(state, data) {
      state.items = data
    }
  },
  actions: {
    loadItems({commit}) {
      Vue.http.get(url).then(res => {
        commit('updateItems',
          res.body)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- КОМПОНЕНТ -->
<template>
 <div> 
  <button @click="search">Click</button>
  {{items}}
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      items() {
        return this.$store.getters.getItems
      }
    },
    methods: {
      search() {
        this.$store.dispatch('loadItems');
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Вариант 2

```html
<!--Store как в первом варианте-->
<!--КОМПОНЕНТ-->
<template>
 <div>
  <button @click="search">Click</button>
  {{items}}
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.$store.getters.getItems
    }
  },
  methods: {
    search() {
      this.$http.get(url)
        .then(response => {
          const items = response.body;
          this.$store.commit('updateItems', items);
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: На каком-то ресурсе видел что не рекомендуется вызывать коммиты в компонентах, а оставить эту прирогативу только экшонам.  Аргументируя тем что это плохой codestyle.

Comment: Я сам тоже только начинаю путь веб разработчика. Местами вызов API нужен только в одном компоненте, а также хочется чтобы состояние компонента сохранилось  после переключений страниц. Получается с одной стороны помещать запрос в экшон vuex для одного раза избыточно, а с другой без него коммиты придётся делать по вашему варианту 2.

Comment: @adrug Тоже читал что для этих целей как раз и используется action. Собственно по этому и спрашиваю, хотелось бы внести больше ясности в этот вопрос тк оба варианта работают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный вариант номер 1.

Во `vuex` для изменения состояния `store` из компонентов нужно использовать `actions`. Потому что мутации должны быть синхронными, для `actions` таких ограничений нет, внутри `actions` можно выполнять асинхронные операции.

Comment: Точно также можно дождаться результата в компоненте и отдать коммит vuex. Тоже получится почти синхронно.

Comment: @adrug вы можете вызвать методы мутирования из компонентов, но вы таким образом делаете:
- переносите ответственность на ваши компоненты, что затрудняет их повторное использование; 
- вводите дополнительные зависимостей между компонентами и мутаторами, что затрудняет поддержание как ваших компонентов, так и методов store;
- смешиваете `store.commit` и `store.dispatch`, делая ваш код более трудным для понимания.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько в комментариях к самому вопросу писал, что иногда обращение к API нужен только одному компоненту. Ради этого помещать его в action `vuex` не хочется. Тут просто смириться выходит? Чтобы поддерживать единый стиль?

Comment: @adrug я написал почему это плохо, вот такое же мнение на гитхабе: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/587